# Редирект для ссылки

Tags: .htaccess

Подскажите, как сделать редирект со страницы 
`main.html?#red?utm_source=werwt&utm_medium=referra` на страницу
`main.php?#red?utm_source=werwt&utm_medium=referra`

По сути ссылка может содержать #red, может #blue
Т.е как написать универсальное правило

Comment: Якоря на сервер не передаются.

Comment: мне кажется вы заблуждатесь

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется данный вариант должен помочь `Redirect 301 /main.html  /main.php`